# How to modify subelements of an early created floor , Revit API

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I created a floor, then I tried to access the `SlabShapeEditor` of this floor, but it returns `None`. How can I modify the sub-elements of this floor in a program?

```
floor = Floor.Create(\_doc,\[floor_profile\],floor_type.Id,level.Id)
shape = floor.SlabShapeEditor
print(shape)
```

It prints `None`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first places to check for any and all Revit API questions is the official Revit SDK. It includes a sample named `SlabShapeEditing`. Have you taken a look at that?